# How do you create a DataContext with different connection strings per user with Autofac and ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, entity-framework-6, autofac, asp.net-identity-2

I am using autofac to resolve dependencies to my asp.net mvc application. Here I am creating the database factory per HTTP request like this.

```
 builder.RegisterType<DatabaseFactory>().As<IDatabaseFactory>().WithParameter("con", SmartSession.Con).InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

Different user will pass different value for parameter "con". My purpose is providing different database connectivity to different user to my deployed application. But here my assumption gone bad. The problem is, to create new instance of databasefactory I have to run the autofac resolver whenever an user wants to login. But it also changes the datacontext for the user who are still using. So my query is how to people handle this kind scenario usually?
I am using EF6 and Identity 2. The repositories uses a BaseRepository which uses the DatabaseFactory. DatabaseFactory returns the datacontext.

```
 public class DatabaseFactory : Disposable, IDatabaseFactory
{
    private SmartEntities _dataContext;
    string con;

    public DatabaseFactory(string con)
    {
        this.con = con;
    }
    public SmartEntities Get()
    {
        return _dataContext ?? (_dataContext = new SmartEntities(con));
    }
    protected override void DisposeCore()
    {
        if (_dataContext != null)
            _dataContext.Dispose();
    }
}
```

In RepositoryBase

```
protected RepositoryBase(IDatabaseFactory databaseFactory)
    {
        DatabaseFactory = databaseFactory;
        _dbset = DataContext.Set<T>();
    }
```

Comment: You might want to show a little more code and explain how this all comes together. Also, I'm sure you've read the docs about [Autofac MVC integration](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnet.html) and [how to work with per-request dependencies](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/per-request-scope.html), right?

Comment: which part of the code you want to see?

Comment: Not just me - anyone who might help. When does the database factory get called? What's in SmartSession.Con? Where is RepositoryBase registered? When is it resolved? Also, have you looked at the Autofac docs? Read the ones about things like resolved parameters? What is working now? What's not working? Which questions or answers have you already searched through (since this sounds like a common question - I'm sure I've seen at least one very similar one on SO)?